# Is there a difference in page paths when on localhost verses deployed?

Tags: react-native, next.js

My app is created in next.js and works great in localhost. When I deployed it in heroku, only the front page shows up and all page paths do not work even though they are correctly inputted in the browser. The only page that is connected to the index.js file in my page paths is the front page. Do the other pages need to also be connected to the indec.js file? I am terribly lost with this issue since the site works perfectly in localhost. In heroku every page path besides / has a 404 error. I didn't add any code to this question since no one file seems relevant to the issue. I've been searching all over for an answer to this issue but can't seem to find any relevant information online since the app is deployed successfully it just won't render any file paths besides /.

Thank you in advance for any help you can offer. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Applications are ran differently on localhost and when deployed to the server. Since you added react tag on the post, I assume you are trying to deploy react native app on Heroku, there is lots of information on internet how to do it.
For example [this post.](https://medium.com/jeremy-gottfrieds-tech-blog/tutorial-how-to-deploy-a-production-react-app-to-heroku-c4831dfcfa08)

Anyway first you need to build your app correctly, so static files would be generated (you didn't mentioned how you are running that app).

**To your question:**
Relative paths are the same on both local and server, but absolute paths will be different.

But for your 404 error I see that no static content are found on the root path.